# Работа приложения под разные версии

Tags: android, android-sdk

В своем приложении я использую фрагменты. Мне потребовалось переопределить внутри экземпляра фрагмента метод `onAttach`, и тут выяснилось следующее: начиная с 23 версии, данный метод вызывается с `Context`: `onAttach(Context)`, а до 23 версии он вызывается с `Activity`: `onAttach(Activity)`.
То есть получается, что для разных версий Android нужен различный код.
Как сделать так, чтобы код одинаково работал на разных версиях Android?

Comment: Что мешает переопределить оба метода и поместит в них идентичный код?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тем что onAttach(Activity) помечается как deprecated

Comment: А второй метод будет работать только для API>23. С этим придётся просто смириться. Пометить аннотациями методы. Один как deprecated, второй пометить targetApi. Пометки исчезнут и всё будет работать

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ - спасибо! Если вы напишете в ответ я с удовольствием поставлю вам галочку как правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один метод помечается как устаревший, а второй метод будет работать только для API>23. С этим придётся просто смириться. Пометить аннотациями методы. Один как deprecated, второй пометить targetApi. Пометки исчезнут и всё будет работать

Comment: Возможно, комментарий про переопределение обоих методов тоже стоит перенести в ответ?

Comment: Да! И большое спасибо за оперативные ответы!

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно использовать `Fragment` из библиотеки поддержки. Они обновляются вместе с самой библиотекой, а не с версией андройда. Поэтому на всех устройствах будет использоваться версия, до которой вы обновите библиотеку поддержки. В этом случае можно использовать единственный метод `onAttach(Context context)`.

Только надо будет заменить стандартный `FragmentManager` на `SupportFragmentManager`, т.е. вызывать `getSupportFragmentManager` вместо `getFragmentManager`. Так же активити должны наследоваться от `AppCompatActivity`.